# Counter scope in plain TeX

Tags: counters, plain-tex

In the following code I intend to implement a loop that calls a macro that increases a count register `\a` on each pass, then displays the values of both `\a` and the loop control variable.

```
\newcount\a\newcount\counter
\def\test{\advance\a by 2 \the\a \quad\the\counter\par}
\loop\advance\counter by 1\ifnum\counter<20 {\test}\repeat
\bye
```

The result (below) shows that the macro always treats `\a` as if it wasn't previously defined. How can I get a global counter to be updated within a macro (for the output to read (2 1, 4 2, 6 3,...)) ?

```
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5 
...
```

Comment: `\global\advance\a`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `\global` since plain TeX counters are `group` safe. Your `\test` macro runs within a group here (unnecessarily!) (Just remove the `{...}`)

```
\newcount\a\newcount\counter
\def\test{\global\advance\a by 2 \the\a \quad\the\counter\par}
\loop\advance\counter by 1\ifnum\counter<20 {\test}\repeat
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer was to call `\test` w/o it being enclosed in braces.